# Vert.x dispatch event to other instance only

Tags: java, publish-subscribe, vert.x

I have several instances with a *verticle* that listens to a specific topic and I want to dispatch an event to this topic from one of these instances to another.

The problem is, that one instance both dispatches and consumes the same event.

How can I prevent an instance from receiving messages from itself?

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to initialize a ***unique identifier*** for each instance and introduce that id within the published messages.

When consuming the message, the instance will check for the *unique identifier* of the publisher and won't handle the message unless it comes from the different instance (the *unique identifier* is different that the instance one).

*Note: I can't illustrate through an example since you have not provided your verticle source code.*